# How do I show a view within another view in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to tweak this code from Apple so that instead of using images for both views, I want to use xib instead: 
[ViewTransitionsAppDelegate.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Listings/Classes_ViewTransitionsAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007411-Classes_ViewTransitionsAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4)

What would I have to do so that both views can be controlled and designed from separate XIB files?

Comment: Tip: have a go at the problem and only if you cannot get it working, post code - you'll far more likely to get lots of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 XIB files, one with each `UIImageView`, add and connect IBOutlet's to each image view and load each XIB when required, with something like `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myImageView1" owner:self]` and `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myImageView2" owner:self]`.

Comment: Do they have to be image views? Can they just be regular views? I created just regular views on put labels on each of them. Then I changed the type in the .h file to UIView instead of UIImageView. How do I now assign in the .m file each view to its respective xib file? How do I use that line you gave me above?

Comment: No, they can be `UIView` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly clear on what you are trying to do... but couldn't you just add one view as a subview of the other after creating the views in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the views for each view controller, and reference those classes in the final view you want to see them, and add them as subview to that view.

```
class1 *object1; class2*object2;

//set frame size for the view of each object 

[self.view addSubview: object1.view];
[self.view addSubview: object2.view];
```